Youtube and other social media sites is not connecting on my windows 11
When i try to open youtube, it is not connecting. It Giving the error message like
"Your connection is not private"

Please help me to solve this problem.
I tried to open youtube or any social media sites, it saying the error message as "Your connection is not private". I asked to chatgpt and gemnini but none of solutions works. The error message is like below

Please give a step by step procedure to solve this issue. Thanks in advance...

Your host's DNS may be awaiting BGP announcement (IPs to change) so it's not seeing a lot of these sites correctly yet. You can maybe try changing your network DNS to CloudFlare's or Google's for faster ASN resolution.

This issue is generally out of the clients hand unless your system has been compromised but you may see similar with multiple devices on the same network. In such case wait it out or clean the system if required.

A few things to check: 1) your local time, 2) the timezone set on your computer, 3) the contents of C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file.
